# Jquery AJAX return from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

New to using this Jquery AJAX method. So i'm making an AJAX call with Jquery, In my PHP script i'm checking a condition to be true from my Database, before I pass in my datastring and bind the variables, then execute that query. Both the script and Database insert work correctly.

My question is, how can I get it to display the error message in my AJAX call on return from my PHP script?

**JS**

---

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'submit_form.php',
data: dataString,
error: function() { alert('Error'); },
success: function() { alert('Success'); }
});
```

### **SUBMIT_FORM.PHP**

```
if ( count of rows in db < x  )
 {

return false;
exit();

}
```

> if this condition is true I want to stop execution of my script and execute
>   the error condition in my AJAX function.

---

```
elseif ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO blah (stuff, morestuff) values (?, ?)")) {

 /* Bind our params */
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $param1, $param1);

        /* Set our params */
$param1= $_POST["name"];
$param2= $_POST["email"];


/* Execute the prepared Statement */
$stmt->execute();
/* Close the statement */
$stmt->close(); 
}
```

> if the first condition is false then I want to return the success function in my ajax call which it is currently doing.

Comment: both are success ....as far as ajax is concerned

Comment: This can be helpful,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417690/return-errors-from-php-run-via-ajax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To invoke the error handler of your `$.ajax`, you can write the following code in PHP (for FastCGI):

```
header('Status: 404 Not found');
exit;
```

Alternatively, use `header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found')` if you're not using FastCGI.

Personally I wouldn't use this approach, because it blurs the line between web server errors and application errors.

You're better off with an error mechanism like:

```
echo json_encode(array('error' => array(
    'message' => 'Error message',
    'code' => 123,
)));
exit;
```

Inside your success handler:

```
if (data.error) {
    alert(data.error.message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute error command in jquery you can try using:
`throw new Exception("Invalid");` inside your php code (where error should invoke).

This will cause http server to return error code 500 to your javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

YOur concept is wrong. error condtion means error in ajax call
Change your code to this

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'submit_form.php',
data: dataString,
error: function() {
 alert('Error'); //here the error is the error in ajax call.eg failing to call or a 404..etc
 },
success: function(msg) {
if(msg=='error'){
   alert('Error'); //this is the error you are looking for
}else{
 alert('Success'); 
}

}
});
```

Your PHP

```
if ( count of rows in db < x  )
 {
echo 'error'; //this is  enough
exit;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are little confused about jquery error setting, according to jquery

> error : A function to be called if the request fails.

so your error code will be fired only because  of the following reasons

> 404 Error – ajax file not found error
>
> 500 Error – ajax internal system error