# How to make jQuery/Ajax log in return "Wrong credentials" error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making a dynamic PHP page with MySQL that has users log in. I recently changed the login, to jQuery/AJAX to make it more smooth and not lose the current page users are in. The thing is that when I miss my log in credentials it doesn't how any message and I want it to do so.

Here is my form :

```
<form id="ajax-login-form" action="session/login.php" method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Login</label>
                    <input type="text" name="u" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Log in" value="" autocomplete="off">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="p" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-5 pull-right">
                            <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Log In">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

My jQuery/Ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//From insert
$("#login-submit").click(function () {
    var $form = $('#ajax-login-form');
    $form.submit(false);
    $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serializeArray(), function (info) {
        $("#result").html(info)
    })
    location.reload();
});
});
```

And finally my php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$lig = mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or
die ("Problema na ligação ao servidor MYSQL");
mysql_select_db("demo", $lig);

$u=$_REQUEST['u'];
$p=$_REQUEST['p'];

$sql="select numuti,nome,nomeutilizador,codtipo,reset from utilizadores where nomeutilizador='$u' and password=md5('$p')";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1)
{
    $lin = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $lin['nomeutilizador'];
        $_SESSION['nivel'] = $lin['codtipo'];
        $_SESSION['reset'] = $lin['reset'];
        //$_SESSION['foto']  = $lin['imagem'];
        $_SESSION['nome']  = $lin['nome'];
        $_SESSION['cod']= $lin['numuti'];
}else{
echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <strong><center>Login Inválido, Tente Novamente</center></strong>
            </div>";
}
?>
```

This is probably a duplicate question, but I couldn't find a reliable answer to my issue, I tried making the errors with divs as you can see in my login.php page.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: MD5 is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: @AlexHowansky This is nothing big, this is a project for school, and this is what they use, thank you for the reference for future work, I just need the messages, I am aware of md5 hashing and mysql_*  functions, The help I need is in the ajax...

Comment: @garek007 3.2.1

Comment: Would be better if you could use version 2, might be more stable and/or compatible. Are you required to use the latest?

Comment: @garek007 yes I am required to use the latest because of the functions I've used in other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Basics

If you are using old `mysql_connect` function vulnerable to SQL injections you do not need any other security .. your system will be permeable.

First you need to do is switch to better methods like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

## jQuery

I recommend to use `submit()` function instead of `click()` and `ajax()` instead of `post()` to better manipulation with data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#ajax-login-form').submit(function(e) {
      var form = this;

      e.preventDefault();
      var username = $("#username").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();

      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'Your-login-url',
          data: {
              username: username,
              password: password
          },
          success: function(data) {
              // do your PHP login and echo 1 if authentication was successfull
              if(data === 1) {
                  form.submit();
              } else {
              // show alert or something that user has wrong credentials ...
                  $("#error_notif").show();
              }
          }
      });
  });

});
```

## HTML

Another thing is error notification. I like to add error div right into the form or form container but set it as hidden. You can show it after jQuery Ajax ends with 0.

```
<div id="error_notif">You used wrong credentials.</div>

<style>
#error_notif {
   display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have only 1 issue, what do I have to import for that ajax to work, because my ajax does not work like that do not no why... it doesn't recognize `$('#ajax-login-form').submit(function(e) {`

Comment: jQuery v2 is required for this - `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I placed on the url `sessao/login.php` and I did the ecos, and when I it logs in I go to this blank page, it is not redirecting me back to where I was, could you help me also with this? by the way it goes to the `sessao/login.php`

Comment: This works, but it has an issue. When I enter the wrong login data it shows the error but when I reenter the correct data it won't submit and you need to reload the page.  Any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your post statement to this

```
$.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serializeArray(), function (info) {
        $("#result").html(info)
    }).fail(function(){
    alert("Login unsuccessful, please try again.");
});
```

Comment: I thought the php was already failing? In any case you should be able to just break the syntax somewhere to return an error

Comment: I tried it, but you sure this is jquery v3 because its not detecting the fail, and just redirects me to the form url, with a blank page.. and doesn't do nothing else.

Comment: That should trigger the error and should be valid, even for version 3. I think your php must not be failing. You can try to force failure using the answer from this post (return a status other than 200)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417690/return-errors-from-php-run-via-ajax